# Why can't Jest find my TypeScript modules?

Tags: typescript, jestjs, babeljs

I'm using a combination of Jest and Babel to test my TypeScript project. Until recently, I was using imports without extensions (as recommended by the [TypeScript error you get when trying to use a `.ts` extension](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/39965#issue-675660588)). The combination worked fine with Jest, but when compiling, the resulting files still had no extensions on their imports, so couldn't be executed.

I changed to using a `.js` extension on my imports, which still works outside of Jest, and produces usable output when compiling, but now Jest can no longer find my TypeScript modules:

```
$ npx jest
 FAIL  src/__test__/index.test.ts
  ● Test suite failed to run

    Cannot find module '../index.js' from 'src/__test__/index.test.ts'

    > 1 | import { foobar } from '../index.js';
        | ^
      2 |
      3 | describe('index', () => {
      4 |   it('works', () => {

      at Resolver.resolveModule (node_modules/jest-resolve/build/resolver.js:324:11)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/__test__/index.test.ts:1:1)

----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File      | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files |       0 |        0 |       0 |       0 |                   
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       0 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        0.526 s
Ran all test suites.
```

I've even tried splitting the difference and including extensions in my source files and omitting them in my tests, but it just moves the error from the test files to the source files.

My configuration is as follows:

`babel.config.json`

```json
{
  "presets": [
    [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      { "targets": { "esmodules": true }, "modules": false }
    ],
    ["@babel/preset-typescript", { "onlyRemoveTypeImports": true }]
  ],
  "env": {
    "test": {
      "presets": [["@babel/preset-env", { "targets": { "esmodules": true } }]],
      "sourceMaps": true
    }
  }
}
```

`jest.config.json`

```json
{
  "collectCoverage": true,
  "coverageDirectory": "coverage",
  "coverageProvider": "v8",
  "errorOnDeprecated": true,
  "resetMocks": true,
  "restoreMocks": true
}
```

`package.json`

```json
{
  "name": "repro-jbt",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "description": "A reproduction of an issue with Jest, Babel, and TypeScript.",
  "type": "module",
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc && babel --extensions '.ts' --ignore '**/__test__/*' --source-maps --out-dir dist src",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "license": "BSD-3-Clause",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.16.7",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.16.7",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.16.7",
    "@types/jest": "^27.4.0",
    "jest": "^27.4.7",
    "ts-node": "^10.4.0",
    "typescript": "^4.5.4"
  }
}
```

`tsconfig.json`

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "alwaysStrict": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "emitDeclarationOnly": true,
    "exactOptionalPropertyTypes": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noImplicitOverride": true,
    "noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature": true,
    "noUncheckedIndexedAccess": true,
    "outDir": "dist/",
    "strict": true,
    "target": "ESnext"
  },
  "exclude": ["**/__test__/*"],
  "include": ["src/"]
}
```

How can I write imports which work both when compiling and testing? Have I misconfigured something?

Answer (score 0):

I'm almost 100% convinced this isn't the *intended* solution, but it did work for me.

Adding a "resolver" to your Jest configuration allows you to execute a custom function when Jest looks for a file. The resolver below works by running the default resolver, but rather than simply passing through errors caused when resolving file names, it tries looking for alternate extension before giving up. If none of the alternatives work, either, the original error is re-thrown.

##### `jest.config.json`

```json
{
  "resolver": "<rootDir>/jest.resolver.cjs"
}
```

##### `jest.resolver.cjs`

```js
const EXTENSION_REPLACEMENTS = [
  { from: ".js", to: [".cjs", ".mjs", ".ts", ".cts", ".mts"] },
  { from: ".jsx", to: [".tsx"] },
];

module.exports = function resolver(request, options) {
  try {
    return options.defaultResolver(request, options);
  } catch (error) {
    for (const { from, to } of EXTENSION_REPLACEMENTS) {
      if (request.slice(-from.length) === from) {
        for (const ext of to) {
          try {
            return options.defaultResolver(
              request.slice(0, -from.length) + ext,
              options,
            );
          } catch {
            // If nothing works, the original error will be re-thrown, so this
            // one is unneeded.
          }
        }
      }
    }

    // None of the replacement extensions worked; re-throw the original error.
    throw error;
  }
};
```